# Cycle through div content on click without Jquery

Tags: javascript

I've got the following code which works as intended.  It shows the first content div, and then on button click, it rotates to content-2, content-3 etc.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
            i = 0;

        function cycle() {
            divs.fadeOut(400).delay(400).eq(i).fadeIn(400);
            i = ++i % divs.length;
        };
        cycle()

        $('button').click(cycle);
        // click button to show next paragraph
    });
```

Unfortunately, the embedded content I'm using doesn't support external libraries, so I need to get this into raw Javascript.

Can anyone point me in the direct direction to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var counter=2;
function cycle(){   
document.getElementsByClassName("content")[counter].style.opacity=0;
 counter++;
 if(counter==3){
 counter=0;
 }
 document.getElementsByClassName("content")[counter].style.opacity=1;
}



window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(){cycle();});
cycle();
}
```

And then css

```
.content{
transition:all ease 3s;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, something has to be wrong somewhere.  I can't seem to get this to work.
I've placed your code in script tags in the head, but no joy.  I can't get it to work on a normal html page either

Comment: Ive updated it. The only thing you have to change is id="content" -> class="content"

Comment: I dont think the even listener is triggering.  Take a look at my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ro89gah3/1/

Comment: Oh no. Not again. Its window.onload not body.onload. :/

Comment: Ah great, thanks.  Now I just need to stack the divs on top of each other and only show content-1 at the start :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it by css. [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) can be helpful.

An approach for something like what you are trying can be:

```
<div id="animatedDiv">Animated DIV</div>


<script>
    document.getElementById("animatedDiv").className = "animated fadeOut";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("animatedDiv").className = "animated fadeIn rotateIn";
    }, 800)
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/acor/hnv8ykbp/)

Comment: Thanks, but I can use external css either :(

Comment: why not? take a look to my fiddle

Comment: The implementation system I'm using doesn't allow for it